# Why does pool.join() hangs when using IPython magic %reset to clear the variable space?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, spyder

Happy new year!

I am new to the Python `multiprocessing` module. To better understand how `apply_async` works, I wrote down the short script below. The script hangs unless I comment the second line out (`get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')`).
Can someone please tell me why this is happening? I am working under Python 3.5 using the Spyder IDE.

The reason why I am using the IPython magic %reset is because I want to clear all variables before running my script and I read on [this webpage](https://gist.github.com/stsievert/8655158355b7155b2dd8) that the IPython magic %reset is an equivalent to `clear all` from Matlab/Octave.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
import random
import multiprocessing

def stakhanov(chunk_idx):
    data=random.randint(1,10) # create random integer between 1 and 10:
    frame_idx=chunk_idx
    return (frame_idx,data)

def stakhanov_finished(result):
    (frame_idx,data)=result
    DATA_READ[frame_idx]=data

def start_multiprocess_io():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES)  # create pool of all processes:
    chunk_idx = 0
    for i in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
        pool.apply_async(stakhanov,args=(chunk_idx,),callback=stakhanov_finished)
        chunk_idx += 1
    pool.close()
    pool.join() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global NUM_PROCESSES, DATA_READ
    NUM_PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # number of CORES
    DATA_READ = [None for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES)] # declare list
    start_multiprocess_io()
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? (I know nothing of ipython itself but there's an obvious potential Windows-y problem here.)

Comment: Hi Torek! Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am currently on Windows. I will try to run my code on a Linux machine and will let you know how it works.

Comment: Hi again Torek! I confirm that my script runs alright under Linux... So your intuition was right: this is indeed a Windows-related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I don't know what the `get_ipython.magic` call does, but in the absence of someone who does, let's look at how multiprocessing works on Windows, and why this line:

```
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
```

is probably wrong.  Probably, that should be hidden underneath the same `if __name__ == '__main__'` test that you have later.

(If moving the line fixes the problem, you can stop here, but it's worth reading the rest if you want to use the multiprocessing code effectively.)

---

When you create a `multiprocessing.Process` or `Pool` instance, the `multiprocessing` module spawns an extra Python instance for the new process.  This is similar to Linux, except that there is no `fork` so it cannot copy the *current* process.  This new spawned process is an all-new, fresh, *empty* Python.

The empty-so-far Python runs with particular arguments.  These vary a bit between Python 2.7 and Python 3.6+; here, I'll quote a fairly long bit from 2.7:

```
def get_command_line():
    '''
    Returns prefix of command line used for spawning a child process
    '''
    if getattr(process.current_process(), '_inheriting', False):
        raise RuntimeError('''
        Attempt to start a new process before the current process
        has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
        forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')

    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        return [sys.executable, '--multiprocessing-fork']
    else:
        prog = 'from multiprocessing.forking import main; main()'
        opts = util._args_from_interpreter_flags()
        return [_python_exe] + opts + ['-c', prog, '--multiprocessing-fork']
```

The 3.6 code splits this up a bit and [has this fragment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f190eb59e60e2ae7a7cbd396458389a7a076e0d3/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L82-L89):

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    return ([sys.executable, '--multiprocessing-fork'] +
            ['%s=%r' % item for item in kwds.items()])
else:
    prog = 'from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(%s)'
    prog %= ', '.join('%s=%r' % item for item in kwds.items())
    opts = util._args_from_interpreter_flags()
    return [_python_exe] + opts + ['-c', prog, '--multiprocessing-fork']
```

Either way, what happens at this point is that the new Python should import a module from `multiprocessing` and run a function in that module.  The function, either `main()` or `spawn_main()`, loads some information from the process that created it—*your* process—to find out what program was run.

This all may depend on you to `import multiprocessing` and call `freeze_support`, if you are using a frozen Python.  This is the *first* branch of the `if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` test: the problem that is being worked-around here is that `-c 'from multiprocessing ...'` option does not function in a frozen Python. ( If you're not using frozen Pythons, the `-c` line takes care of most things.)

Anyway, the upshot is that your new Python runs this special `main` or `spawn_main`, which connects back to *your* Python process, the one you started yourself.  From your Python, the new Python obtains name of the original main module, and it *imports it*.

It imports it with a regular old `import` (well, with a special slightly hacked-up import, and again the details vary a bit by Python version).  This means that `__name__` is *not* `__main__` but instead is `main` or `program` or whatever you named your `main.py` file.  This allows the multiprocessing code to get access to your entire program.

Next, the multiprocessing code figures out what function you wanted to run, from which module.  (This is all handled through the `pickle` system, which is why you can only run functions that can be pickled, passing arguments that can be pickled.)  Having set up all the communication required between your original Python and this new Python that's running the process, the new Python can now call that function, let it do its thing, and when it returns, have the new Python process terminate.

***All of this depends on the fact that when the new Python process runs `import main` or `import prog` or whatever it is that gets your original program loaded, its executable code is protected by a test using `if __name__`***.  This makes sure that *that* code—your program's main workings—*don't* get run in the spawned sub-Python.  Instead, *only* the `multiprocessing.main` or `multiprocessing.spawn_main` actually *runs*.  Everything from your main program gets *imported and defined*, so that all the functions are available to be *called* once their names show up via the pickling code.  But none of them *run* yet.

You can violate this rule,<sup>1</sup> and run specific bits of code, *if and only if* they don't break the setup sequence required to run a `Process` instance.  It seems clear enough, based on the problem seen here, that `get_ipython.magic('reset -sf')` breaks the setup sequence.

---

<sup>1</sup>One case where you *must* run specific bits of code is if you must augment `sys.path` to insert the location from which some code is imported.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Torek!
So if I understand properly, it is not a good idea to clear all variables at the beginning of the script, since the "new" Python imports the main module to allow the multiprocessing code to access the entire program...

Comment: Yes, at least in this case. On Linux and other Unix-y systems, the multiprocessing `Process` instance creation uses `fork` rather than `spawn`, which lets it avoid the problem.